# Prototyping in flash?

Tags: flash

I know most people hate 100% flash-based websites, but I was recently forced to use flash for a college assignment. After creating a fully-featured ria in less than 2 weeks with every feature I could imagine, i've regrettably fallen in love with this beast (which I previously refused to touch with a stick) due to the power of AS3 and the ability to sprinkle it everywhere :-\

I now want to port a commercial desktop application of mine (which has been largely unsuccesful) to the web and feel flash/flex is an excellent candidate. While creating a html/css/js version would be ideal (working browser shortcuts, for a start), i'm certain it'll take a year to create in cross-browser html/css/js what would take just ~3 months in flash. Obviously as the (paid) desktop product was unsuccessful, i'd want to minimize the risk/investment in the (free) web application.

I plan on using JSON for web services, so it shouldn't be a huge pita to port in the future.

Is this a good strategy for launching a web app you're not yet 100% committed to? Or will the fact i'm using flash doom me from the start? Has anybody else done this? If so, how did your userbase respond to the 100% usage of flash, and did you get around to porting it to standard web technologies?

Comment: My subjective opinion is that in the long term Flash will be replaced by HTML5/Canvas+js technology...

Comment: I honestly think most people couldn't care less about the technology behind a program/application as long as it works as it should and is responsive. As you're not going to be making money with this, then it's really up to you to decide how much time you can afford to put into it.

Comment: Build it in html/css/js. Only build for browsers you NEED to support. Only build the core features you NEED for the application to work. Release. You will then discover if there is any interest in it. If you are "relieving a pain" people won't care if it doesn't have hundreds of options. Positive feedback will give you the motivation to add all your other features and let you know if it's worth porting it to older/obscure browsers. Or you will have saved yourself some wasted time. Better to release something than lose interest in a couple of months and never release anything. IMHO

Comment: Just try not to go against the user's expectations, for example don't break the back button.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Trevor. That's how I used to think back when I started programming and was having fun (before I took my work too seriously). I'm going to go ahead and release a minimal (imperfect) site, and develop in response to popularity/demand.

Answer (score 0):

Flex/Flash Builder can be a good option but the mobile device limitations are enough to use something else. I agree with Trevor that html and javascript are the way to go. Specifically you should use a js framework like jquery because it has jquery UI and mobile out of the box including most ui features Flex was pioneering a few years ago. using the jquery ajax call you can easily use jsonp.